# how many times does i occur in x (unsigned 32 bit int C)

Tags: c, int, sum, unsigned

This is a little bit confusing for me, but I have to see how many times i occurs in x.
So if someone types 3 for i and x is 4294967295, it should then say 0 times, but if someone types in 9 for i and 4294967295 for x, it should say 3 times.

This is what I have, but output says 0 with 9, so it's not working ..

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned int i;
    scanf("%u", &i);
    unsigned int x;
    scanf("%u", &x);
    int output = 0;
    int t = 0;
    while (t < 10) {
        x /= 10;
        if (i == x) {
            output++;
        }
        t++;
    }
    printf("%d", output);
}
```

Comment: You are using `t` uninitialized is seems.

Comment: `output` is not initialized, too.

Comment: Why convert the input to unsigned ints?  Treating the string as a string and checking each character would be simpler.

Comment: In your number, `x` will never be 9, only 429, 42949 and 429496729. Check against `x % 10 == i`, but _before_ dividing by 10. Your loop condition can then be just `while (x)` and you can remove `t`.

Comment: You you are working with is a property of strings, not numbers. I suggest you use string functions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    unsigned int i;
    scanf("%u", &i);
    if(i > 9) {                                 // check it's a single digit
        printf("expecting a single digit\n");
        return 1;                               // to indicate failure
    }

    unsigned int x;
    scanf("%u", &x);

    int output = 0;      // initialized output, removed t (use x directly instead)
    if(x == 0) {         // special case if x is 0
        if(i == 0) {
            output = 1;
        }
    } else {

        while(x > 0) {         // while there is at least a digit
            if(i == (x % 10)) {  // compare to last digit
                output++;
            }
            x /= 10;            // remove the last digit
        }

    }

    printf("%d\n", output);    // added \n to be sure it's displayed correctly
    return 0;                  // to indicate success

}
```

Also I recommend using more explicit variable names, like `digit` and `number` instead of `x` and `i`.

Comment: if the input would be i 0 and x 0, output should be 1, because 0 is the same as 0, but output is 0 instead

Comment: indeed, I didn't think of this special case. It's now fixed.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! That optional block also is nice, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a good idea to check that the user really inputs a single digit : I edited to add this.

Comment: That's quite some obscure coding style there... why the aversion towards the enter key and indention? This code is asking for bugs.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you compare `i` with the *whole* of `x`, instead of checking each digit of `x`.

The easiest solution is probably to read `i` as a character, make sure [it's a digit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit). Then read `x` as a string (and make sure it's all digits as well). Then for each character in the string `x` compare it against `i`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it did work indeed, but was getting not the good results. Code from Antoine solved the issue

Answer (score 3):

You should extract each digit from `x` and compare it against the digit `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int i;
    scanf("%u", &i);
    unsigned int x;
    scanf("%u", &x);
    int output = 0;
    int t = 0;
    while(x > 0) {   
        t = x % 10;  // least significant digit of x
        if(t == x) {
            output++;
        }
        x /= 10;  
    }
    printf("%d", output);
}
```